# Unmasked jQuery masked-Money

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I use jQuery to currency my data for this page [Masked-Money](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/), and I want to use 'unmasked' because in my model I have decimal, and commas are not allowed in decimal values.

When I  use without 'unmasked' it works well:

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#Total').maskMoney();
    })
</script>
```

but If I use unmasked, plugin doesn't works

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#Total').maskMoney('unmasked');
    })
</script>
```

What I'm doing wrong, or what can I do to delete comma when I post

Comment: No familiar with that plugin, but you either need to create a custom model binder so that the value can be bound to your property, or you need to intercept the forms `.submit()` event and update the value of the hidden input so its submitted with the 'unmasked' value - e.g. `$('form').submit(function() { var t = $('#Total').maskMoney('unmasked'); $('#Total').val(t); });`

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the demo page, you have two options:

1. Provide some setup to the plugin

   $('#Total').maskMoney({thousands:''});
2. Set some data properties on your input

   @Html.TextboxFor(m => m.Total, new { data_thousands=""})

Update.

Apologies, got the wrong end of the stick.

You would need to tie onto the submit event as stephen says and change the value to the correct version.  something like this.

```
$(function(){
    $("form").submit(function() {
        $('#Total').val($('#Total').maskMoney('unmasked')[0]);
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that my `unmasked` function is not working, it doesn't remove the commas from my input value before I submit it.

Comment: The maskMoney({thousands:''});  part is what I was looking for when I landed here via Google.  my issue was the comma in the currency was sending back a split string with the 1st value only

Answer (score 2):

That really worked for me:

```
  $("#form-id").submit(function(){
    var value = $('#input-value-id').maskMoney('unmasked')[0];
    $('#input-value-id').val(value);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

i have many input in a single form That's why i used the following codes

```
$('.field').maskMoney('destroy');
$('.field').maskMoney({thousands:'', decimal:'.'});
$('.field').maskMoney('mask');
```